# NullPointerException while starting Spring Shell on Heroku worker node

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, spring-shell

Recently we are facing an issue that we cannot start our Spring Shell app on our Heroku worker node anymore. Directly after the shell app has started the console just prints `java.lang.NullPointerException` a million times (like there is kina a loop that is trying to instantiate a bean or something which is failing all the time).

Here is an excerpt:

```
Running /env.sh java -jar ops.jar on ⬢ foo... up, worker.8633 (Standard-1X)

2022-03-04 07:44:37.221  INFO 5 --- [           main] ...Application        : Starting Application v1.0.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.11 on 2e0b87b1-cecd-4720-8c27-4d39afba9615 with PID 5 (/ops.jar started by u27375 in /)
2022-03-04 07:44:37.226  INFO 5 --- [           main] ...Application        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-04 07:44:38.012  INFO 5 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-04 07:44:38.129  INFO 5 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 110 ms. Found 10 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-04 07:44:38.886  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-03-04 07:44:38.948  INFO 5 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
2022-03-04 07:44:39.127  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-03-04 07:44:39.547  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-03-04 07:44:39.929  INFO 5 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-03-04 07:44:39.948  INFO 5 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2022-03-04 07:44:41.089  INFO 5 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-03-04 07:44:41.098  INFO 5 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-04 07:44:42.590  INFO 5 --- [           main] ...Application        : Started Application in 5.939 seconds (JVM running for 6.39)
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

We use Spring Boot `v2.6.4` and Spring Shell `v2.0.1.RELEASE`. The Spring Shell app is containerized (Docker) and we usually start it with:

```
heroku run --type worker -a foo -- /env.sh java -jar ops.jar
```

Does anyone of you guys have some tips or something on how to solve or even how to debug this further, i.e., to print the whole stacktrace of the exception?

Could this be something related to `JLine` in a way that in cannot be used in a Docker container together with Heroku?! However, this worked like a charm in the past.

As said, we appreciate any hint or tip on how to debug this further.

Cheers